# Migrating wordpress featured images

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to migrate some articles from one wordpress database to another, without deleting anything. The problem is that I cannot transfer the thumbnails. I transfer the files, I add the  post and postmeta in the database, but it just can't happen, any help? Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you copy your content from `\uploads` directory where the images stored?

Comment: Have you update your site url in db? Check your console if there is any network error

Comment: I transfer only some articles, not whole website

Comment: Did your migrate your database? If so then you need to change image url. Also if possible then provide your site link so that we may have a look as well

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the Plugin Updraft Plus? There's a free Version which might do your business with a few clicks.